# Get value with $_POST from multiple brackets

Tags: post

```
<input type="text" class="text" id="attachments-1-vid_id" name="attachments[1][vid_id]" value="1qaq0F-SXpo8">
<input type="text" class="text" id="attachments-2-vid_id" name="attachments[2][vid_id]" value="2qaq0F-SXpo8">
<input type="text" class="text" id="attachments-3-vid_id" name="attachments[3][vid_id]" value="3qaq0F-SXpo8">
<input type="text" class="text" id="attachments-4-vid_id" name="attachments[4][vid_id]" value="4qaq0F-SXpo8">
```

This is my input. I want to check it with only **[vid_id]**. Is it possible?

If any input posted

```
if( isset($_POST['vid_id']) ) {
//do it...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the `vid_id` index which isn’t really what is passed in the $_POST superglobal.

The solution is based on two assumptions.

1. Only that input exist.

This is pretty straight forward:

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST[‘attachments’][231][‘vid_id’]){}
```

OR

```
<?php
  if(array_key_exists(“vid_id”, $_POST[‘attachments’][231])){}
```

2. Similar inputs also exist and you want to perform for multiple inputs.

By this, I mean..

```
<input type=text name=attachments[][vid_id] />
.....
<input type=text name=attachments[][vid_id] />
<input type=text name=attachments[][vid_id] />
```

For this, you have to insert it in a loop.

```
<?php
 foreach($_POST[‘attachments’] as $arr){
       if(array_key_exists(“vid_id”, $arr){
            // do stuff
       }
 }
```

Comment: all inputs has different id. i want to check just any vid_id posted. foreach way doesn't work.

Comment: Are all of them refered by the same index?

Comment: Yes. All in the same index.

Comment: Now because the index is the same... which I bet is vid_id... it’ll work the same way... because using the index.. what the code checks is if the index vid_id exists... somif it does.. something should happen

Comment: I can't explain. Can you check my question again?

Comment: To see what i mean... type `echo ‘<pre>’ .  print_r($_POST, true) . ‘</pre>’ in` the action page of your form